# Call a selfhosted endpoint once an application has started?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I have an application which exposes some endpoints which access a foreign system.

I need my application which exposes the endpoints, to call one of its own endpoints 
like a POST request with a payload which can feed the foreign system?

How do I call an endpoint which the application, itself, is hosting as part of its startup?

Perhaps through the launch setting be an option - but these are usually get requests so how do I modify to be a POST request with a payload?